# "in eleven minutes" / "over eleven minutes"

Tags: phrase-usage

I just updated a status saying that 'a lot could happen **over eleven minutes**'
I know that it should normally be written '**in eleven minutes**'
but we had an incident which made eleven minutes look like quite a long time and I thought using 'over' instead of 'in' would emphasize the length of time.

For example, people say 'things change over a period of time' just to mention the longevity, and in the same way, I used 'over' to mention that eleven minutes is a really long time

Was that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The original poster is correct that "a lot can happen in eleven minutes" is idiomatic.

However, "a lot could happen over eleven minutes" is acceptable.  It could mean any of the following:

> "a lot could happen over the next eleven minutes"
>
> "a lot can happen during eleven minutes"
>
> "a lot can happen in eleven minutes"

If the meaning is "a lot could happen over the next eleven minutes", then it is important to say something quickly in the status message.  Taking three minutes to choose the best wording would probably be worse than saying something (that is good enough) quickly.

Comment: @avinash -- If you want killer replies, please look up "Snappy Answers to Stupid Questions".  Al Jaffee wrote articles full of them for *Mad Magazine*.  Don Rickles was also famous for his put-downs.  I prefer Dale Carnegie's approach, myself.  Carnegie wrote an entire book on how to *Win Friends and Influence People*.  The pre-1955 editions were the best.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to say this, however I would say:

> Anything could happen **in/during** the next eleven minutes.

Using "next" emphasizes your concern during that time period.

And "anything" emphasizes how time passes, since there are so many possibilities contained in "anything".